# Beginner level Method call in C#

Tags: c#

What is wrong with the method call below?

I created the following method:

```
public static int GetInteger(string Prompt, int LowRange, int HighRange, out int ErrCode)
```

Then, I tried to call it:

```
string Str;

int ErrCode;

int Value = GetInteger ("Gimme a number: ", 0, 1000, ErrCode);
```

I suspect it is wrong because it is not have "out" before "ErrorCode in the last parenthesis.

Comment: As you mentioned, you need to use the out keyword for out parameter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier

Comment: *"I suspect it is wrong because it is not have "out" before "ErrorCode in the last parenthesis"* Surely you could test your suspicion and try it? Did it solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the out keyword in front of each out paramater

try this:

```
int errCode;
int Value = GetInteger ("Gimme a number: ", 0, 1000, out errCode);
```

or

```
int Value = GetInteger ("Gimme a number: ", 0, 1000, out int errCode);
```